# How does the fac on Mix Shader work?

Tags: shaders

So if I plug in a black and white image to the fac of the mix shader node, what is happening? What's the difference between when A and B is connected to each socket and when A and B is switched to the other socket(basically switching two lines of wires each other)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fac input in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58165/fac-input-in-blender)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you connect a BW image into the *FAC* input of the *Mix Shader*:

Black areas mean A
White areas mean B

[image]

**When using the FAC slider:**
0 means A
1 means B

[image]

**Universal rule:**
For all nodes (roughness, metalness, fac...)
Black means 0, white means 1.
You can use gradual transition as well.